# Is [ConcurrencyCheck] decoration non-functional?

Tags: concurrency, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to implement Optimistic Concurrency checking in a Core project. I display the record to be edited, alter the data in the back end (Sql Server Management Studio), save the data from the web page but no Concurrency exception occurs despite the decoration being on every single field in the Model (except the key).

I read this article:

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/47392764/ef-core-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-does-not-work-as-expected

which appears to explain that the decoration'[ConcurrencyCheck]' does absolutely nothing! It appears to recommend building duplicate, unmapped fields into the model if we use the EF context calls .Update and .SaveChanges (it appears the concurrency comparison happens when .Update retrieves a version of the data the user has never seen for comparison).

This article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency

has an example using RawSQL.

Now, I am OK using RowVersion. I might have used it first if the [ConcurrencyCheck] documentation had included the statement **"Only works with RawSql"**.

Am I reading this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading it wrong enough.  I just automatically used SaveChangeAsync without the await and 
did not consider it would return before the update was completed. I changed it to .SaveChanges and it caught the exception.